# ReactiveMongo: How to convert a BSONArray to List[String]

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

Given the following `BSONDocument`...

```
val values = BSONDocument("values" -> BSONArray("one", "two", "three"))
```

How do I convert it to a `List`? I've tried this...

```
values.getAs[List[String]]("values").getOrElse(List.empty))
```

... but it doesn't work - I always get `List.empty`.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

OK... I think it is worth describing the real case. I ran the `distinct` command and this was the result:

```
values: {
  values: [
    0: BSONObjectID("55d0f641a100000401b7e454")
  ],
  stats: {
    n: BSONInteger(1),
    nscanned: BSONInteger(1),
    nscannedObjects: BSONInteger(1),
    timems: BSONInteger(0),
    cursor: BSONString(BtreeCursor projectId_1)
  },
  ok: BSONDouble(1.0)
}
```

I need to transform `values` to a Scala `List[String]` like this:

```
List("55d0f641a100000401b7e454")
```

Comment: Print the document `values` to check it: `println(s"values: ${BSONDocument pretty values}")`

Comment: See my updated post. Tx ;-)

Comment: The element type not being `BSONString` but `BSONObjectID`, the array cannot be read as `List[String]` but as `List[BSONObjectID]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. First, I've defined a `BSONReader[BSONValue, String]` like this...

```
package object bsonFormatters {

    implicit object BSONValueStringReader extends BSONReader[BSONValue, String] {

     def read(bson: BSONValue) = bson match { 
      case oid: BSONObjectID => oid.stringify 
    }
}
```

... and then just imported it in my companion object like this:

```
import reactivemongo.bson.{BSONString, BSONDocument}
import reactivemongo.core.commands.{CommandError, BSONCommandResultMaker, Command}

case class Distinct(
  collectionName: String,
  field: String,
  query: Option[BSONDocument] = None
) extends Command[Seq[String]] {

  override def makeDocuments = BSONDocument(
    "distinct" -> BSONString(collectionName),
    "key" -> field,
    "query" -> query
  )

  val ResultMaker = Distinct
}

object Distinct extends BSONCommandResultMaker[Seq[String]] {

  import bsonFormatters._ // this makes the trick

  def apply(document: BSONDocument) = CommandError.checkOk(
    document,
    Some("distinct")
  ).toLeft(
    document.getAs[List[String]]("values").getOrElse(List.empty)
  )
}
```

I hope it helps.